# Rain Bird 100-DV-F valve top is stuck on

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a Rain Bird 100-DV-F valve that is being slow to allow water to flow.
I bought a new diaphragm and solenoid filter. I replaced the filter just fine. However, after taking out all 6 screws, the top of the valve will not come off. I've applied significant force and it won't budge.

What could be holding the valve together without the screws?

Comment: I have absolutely no experience with these valves, but I often find it helpful to watch videos of other people taking things apart on Youtube.  Is your valve like the one in this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hI-g8BdfT5A

Comment: Thank you. I have watched several and none of them have shown any signs of this issue.